# Run Python File in ASP.net Core with Value

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i Want Start  **Python** File in **ASP.Net Core** with Value
for Example A Python File With This Path :

> D:\Project\Freelance\QEpanet\Core\Init.py

it's need a Value , For Example "IRAN.inp" Value
How i Should Run it?
it's a Code but Don't Work

```
public class EpanetController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Write()
    {
        try
        {
            Process i = Process.Start("./Python/Init.py", "Iran.inp");
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: ^^ The other thing to consider is: Maybe it's not that good of an idea to allow the Service to start an arbitrary number of python processes. I don't know if you are _obliged_ to use it, but I personally would try and recreate the functionality in C#, so it can be used in-process.

Comment: I want Start a init.py , Send data and Get Resualt !

Comment: In that case, you need to await the exit of the process and read the result. All in all quite cumbersome. As I wrote: it's probably worth it to think about rewriting the functionality in C#. _Or_ you go with some integration like [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) (I am not affiliated with the project) ...

Comment: Even don't Think about rewriting  ! it's a Very "Hard complicated
" Project  about water and Hydraulic System

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd consider integration rather than running it out-of-process. And again: assuming, this is some rather heavy computational lifting, you may want to watch your resources (i.e. limit the number of those processes running at the same time)

Comment: Now i have Another Problem ! I Can Run Python But Now , It's Show me (Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token 'a'')when i Run with IronPython

Comment: That's a good point to ask another question ;D